# serializer showing name of model

Tags: django, security, serialization

I want to serialize data from nested queryset:
I have working code but output from serializer showing too many data. I want hide this for security reason.

example output:
(...)
"gallery": "[{"model": "mainapp.imagesforgallery", "pk": 1, "fields": {"user": 1, "image": "uploads/2022/8/6/drw/Adapta-KDE-theme_JOgL4kO.webp", "thumbnail": ""}}]"
(...)

this is models.py

```
class ImagesForGallery(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'User: {} || Image: {}'.format(self.user, self.image)

class Gallery(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Projects, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_gallery =  models.ManyToManyField(ImagesForGallery, blank=True, related_name='project_gallery')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.project)
```

This is my view

```
class HomeView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProjSerializer
    queryset = Proj.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(HomeView, self).list(request, args, kwargs)
        gal = Gallery.objects.all()
        for d in response.data:
            for g in gal:    
                if d['uuid'] == str(g.project.uuid):
                    qs = g.project_gallery.get_queryset()                
                    serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('json', qs)    
                    d['gallery'] = serialized_obj
                      
        return response
```

This code compares the project model to the photo gallery model. If uuid is correct, include this gallery in the project and send json.

I'm not sure the code is efficient and safe. The question is how to modify the code so that it does not show the model name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your ProjSerializer to serialize your queryset

```py
if d['uuid'] == str(g.project.uuid):
    qs = g.project_gallery.get_queryset()
    serialized_obj = ProjSerializer(qs, many=True).data
    d['gallery'] = serialized_obj
```